# Why can’t I see locally hosted website on same subnet?

Tags: ssl, iis-8

I have a small IIS webserver running in my office for academic purposes.

It is on the same subnet as the rest of my network. `192.168.7.x`

I have a domain running on that server (e.g. `mydomain.com`).
I can reach `mydomain.com` externally, but from the same `192.168.7.x` network, I can't.
I get this site can’t provide a secure connection
`mydomain.com` uses an unsupported protocol. `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

I am using a Let's Encrypt cert on the site which again, works externally.

If I try to connect using `http://` (no cert) I get:
This site can’t be reached
mydomain.com refused to connect. `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I can get to the default IIS website by entering the IP address in my browser.

I'm not sure how to rectify this.
Is it a router issue or a cert issue or an IIS issue?

Comment: How have you habdled dns resolution? This sounds like a hairpin NAT issue to me.  If you hardcode the domain name with its 192.168 address into your hosts file does it start working?

Comment: It works if I hard code the IP in my hosts file

Comment: Here is the NAT rule in my Mikrotik router
https://nbson.com/nat/nat0.png

Comment: Using the hosts file is OK for me but I wonder if I should add a rule where requests from the internal network on port 80 go to the IP of the server

Comment: I dont have experience with microtic gear, but you do have a hairpin nat issue. This is a fairly common problem. In essence, your router does not know that lan requests for the ip associated with its external IP need to be port forwarded - and indeed doing this is often not desireable as it can interfere with loading the devices web interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't intend to bump this arbitrarily but I had exactly this problem with my router.
Initially it worked just fine, then suddenly I could no longer access my server when I was connected internally in the local network, but from outside it worked just fine.

My solution was to reset the router.
That meant for me to remove all rules, restart the router and re-add them again.
After that my router started to work as it used to.

Comment: The proper answer is "hairpin nat".
Either you need to be able to program the router to accommodate for this, or run the website on a different public IP than your local network. 

I use a Mikrotik router and there is some discussion on it here:
https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=172380

Also the workaround is to enter the local IP in your HOSTS file like
192.168.1.40 mydomain.com